# Can you turn a pose into the actual geometry of the mesh?

Tags: mesh, geometry, pose-mode

For example, I move the finger bones so it appears like a rested hand. Is it possible after that to make that pose the actual geometry of the mesh, so when I compile it and put it in game it doesn't go back to the default open hand?

What I posed it like in blender:
[image: What I posed it like in blender]

What it looks like when I compile:
[image: What it looks like when I compile]

I'm new to blender.

Answer (score 5):

Yup.

Pose your armature.  Select your mesh.  Copy the armature modifier, then apply the first (topmost) copy.  Select your armature in pose mode and ctrl-a -> apply pose as resting pose.  Done.

There can be some issues if you have some constraints built around assumptions about the base pose.  It's not possible (to my knowledge) to apply a resting pose only to a single bone, so make sure your armature is in the pose you want before doing it.

Comment: I'm very new to blender, how do I get to the armature modifier?

Comment: @VOKZEL That's very very new.  I would recommend doing some basic tuts first.  I recommend https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro .  Without a little more knowledge than that, you probably don't even have the language for me to be able to tell you.  But in case I'm wrong, the armature modifier is on the modifier tab of the properties view (with your mesh selected.)

Comment: Yeah, I know I'm new, but I'm not planning on animating or creating custom models. What I am using is just a model from some other video game.

But I found out where the armature modifier is, and when I copy it the bones get really buggy and broken.

https://pasteboard.co/HuVMgDh.png

Comment: No, it won't be correct until you do everything.

Comment: I find this confusingly-worded. I know what an armature modifier is (as opposed to an armature) and know how to access them. I know how to copy them onto the clipboard. I have no idea how to apply the "first/topmost" copy, or what that means (topmost in order on the clipboard? topmost in physical location on the outliner? another interpretation) or what to do after that. I recognize that we're basically trying to separate the rig from particular way the mesh is deformed so the latter can be imported onto the original mesh to change its shape, but I have no idea how to actually do that.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE Copy as in create a copy of the modifier on the modifier stack-- as in, duplicate the modifier.  Topmost, as in, in the highest position on the stack, but it really doesn't matter, that's just how you should be applying modifiers in general.  What to do after applying the topmost armature?  Apply the pose of the armature as its rest pose.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter *Object Mode*.
2. Select the mesh attached to the armature.
3. Open the *Object* menu in the upper left of your workspace.
4. Scroll down to *Apply* so all the options under *Apply* are visible.
5. Hit *Apply Visual Geometry to Mesh*.

This should deform the mesh (in *Edit Mode*) to what it currently looks like in *Object* and *Pose Mode*. Deleting the rig after doing this appears to flip the mesh 90 degrees, so keep that in mind.